# Pandas, import multiple csv into one data frame with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import

I have 12 csv files which I wanted to import into a data frame in column wise.

For instance, the each 12 csv files are named differently as follows:

```
filenames = ['experiment_timesteps_1.csv',
             'experiment_timesteps_2.csv',
             'experiment_timesteps_3.csv',
             'experiment_timesteps_4.csv',
             'experiment_timesteps_5.csv',
             'experiment_timesteps_6.csv',
             'experiment_timesteps_8.csv',
             'experiment_timesteps_10.csv',
             'experiment_timesteps_12.csv',
             'experiment_timesteps_15.csv',
             'experiment_timesteps_18.csv',
             'experiment_timesteps_20.csv']
```

I wanted to use the unique file names (11th to the last 4) as column header in a new data frame.  Each file consists of a single column with the same number of rows as follows:

```
results
266430.1827
318881.2395
285411.9195
279878.2699
272394.9219
239213.2243
274932.4677
290705.0974
315464.9616
240384.0452
```

I encountered the error with the execution of the following code:

```
results = DataFrame()
for name in filenames:
    results[name[11:-4]] = read_csv(name, header=0)
```

**ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can do it as follows:

```
results = DataFrame()
for name in filenames:
    aux = read_csv(name)
    results[name[11:-4]] = aux["results"]
```

This will generate a column for each file with the unique identifier you want and the "results" column of each csv will be saved in the corresponding column.